# Implementing simple software updater using rsync

Tags: rsync, auto-update

I'm trying to find a way to update client software while reducing traffic and update server load.

Case:

- Server is just http server that has latest non compressed/packed version of software.
- Client uses rsync to download changes

Does server have to run rsync instance/host/service (idk how to call it) in order to produce delta files?
Seen some forum question about downloading files with rsync. It seemed like server didn't need rsync instance. If server isn't running rsync instance is that download gonna be done without delta files?

Do you know other solutions which can reduce network and server load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>The server doesn't need any special software other than a ssh server.</strike>

I was incorrect about this for your use case. I believe what you are looking for is daemon mode rsync for the server. This has rsync listen on a port to serve requests.

I misunderstood what you were trying to do at first. However in theory it might still be able to be done with only ssh or telnet, I think the daemon mode is a better solution.

See: [SSH vs Rsync Daemon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26182/what-is-the-need-for-rsync-server-in-daemon-mode)

Comment: Thx, how does server produce delta files without that?